# Applying the pigeonhole principle

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Let A ⊆ {1, 2, . . . , 12} with |A| = 5. Prove that there are (a, b),(c, d) ∈ A × A with (a, b) /= (c, d) and a + b = c + d. I know that this requires the use of the pigeon rule but I am a bit confused about how that works or how to apply it here.

Comment: Maybe consider the differences between the elements of $A$?  What can you say about the differences between $a, b, c, d$ if $a+b = c+d$?

Comment: Ask yourself the following questions. How many pairs do you have in $A\times A$? How many distinct possibilities do you have for the sum of coordinates of pairs in $A\times A$? Is it possible for $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ to have distinct sums? These should lead you to the answer.

Comment: Clearly the pairs (a,b) (b,a) work. Are you perhaps asking for when $a\neq b\neq c \neq d$?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)